# Does using site packages installed for 32-bit Python introduce memory limitations if they are also used with 64-bit Python?

Tags: python, memory, 32bit-64bit

**Aside** from the obvious solution of *"just install the respective package(s) with your 64-bit Python version"*, and aside from justifying valid use cases, I am after some technical insight into this scenario.

As an example, say I am running a Python script **with a 64-bit Python version**, which includes something along the lines of below:

```
sys.path.append("some 32 bit Python version site package path")

import some_32bit_library

# do stuff with some_32bit_library...
```

Such that `some_32bit_library` is being imported and used from the 32-bit version of Python.

Even though the overall script is run with a 64-bit Python, will importing and using this `some_32bit_library` introduce a memory limit because it is from a 32-bit version?

I am aware that a 32-bit application itself is limited to accessing ~4GB of memory. The question is, will using the 32-bit library via a Python script running with a 64-bit version also have the same ~4GB limitation?

Any answer/insight would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It simply will not work.  When a package is labeled 32 or 64, that means it contains binary libraries.  You cannot load a 32-bit library into a 64-bit process, nor vice versa.

If the package is Python only (no binary), then it is probably bit-for-bit identical, and will work fine.

Comment: To clarify the library isn't actually labelled "32-bit" i just wrote that to be a generic name for any package, (i.e., the package in question is PyPDF2) and importing and using it does work fine - but what I'm inferring from what you wrote is that no it would not introduce a such memory limitations?

Comment: As long as it has no compiled binaries, there is no problem.